# Is There a Mathematical Symbol For Mutable & Immutable values?

Tags: notation

As per above, is there a symbolical way of identifying a mutable value or an immutable value?

As an example, in my notes, I want to denote the value 'Pi', 'Adam' as immutable, is there a symbol to represent an immutability of a value?

Comment: In mathematics, it's extremely uncommon to have a mutuable variable outside of a code/pseudocode block. Can you describe your intended use case?

Comment: The intended use for more for documentation. As an example, javascript language is awesome, however ,also a bit messy. Some of the functions are mutable & some not. So in my applications documentation, I wanted to make it obvious which is mutable & which are not.

Comment: I would mimic whatever articles in your intended venues do, and if they don't mention it at all and you think it needs to be mentioned, maybe just use a sentence that saying what the important mutable/immutable things are.

Comment: Thanks, I have taken J.G's suggestion to use a custom symbol for identification of mutables & immutables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even if there is one, your readers probably won't recognise your use of it and infer the meaning you intend, suggesting you need to introduce your own convention and make it explicit. Perhaps the simplest is to deitalicise your constants, viz. $\text{e}$ instead of $e$.