# How should I use notation when subjects for predicates have identical first letters?

Tags: notation, predicate-logic

First example.  "Lina is a student", "Li is a student". Please notice that "Li" is a substring of "Lina".

Second example. "Vladimir is a student", "Vladislav is a student", here they partially match, namely first 5 letters (Vladi) are exactly the same.

What should I change in my notation in order to deal with such cases?
Of course I have enough fantasy to make up my own notation to deal with it, but I wonder if there is "official" way (or ways).

Comment: Why "official" notatio ? Use $\text {Li}$ and $\text {Lina}$ respectively for the two individual *constants*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Do you suggest writing SLi and SLina respectively? Or Sli and Slina?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any official way to do it. If you want to use $\dagger$ for Li and $わ$ for Lina, you're welcome to do that.

The only real requirement is that you're consistent, and that you do not use those symbols for anything else. As a second thing, which is nice to aim for but not a requirement at all, is that it is easy for your readers to remember which is which.

Comment: So it's not frowned upon in math to make up your own notation?

Comment: @user161005 Not if there's nothing well-known that would suit. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2436620

Comment: @user161005 I wouldn't go changing the addition symbol, or any of the ten digits, but for notation which is probably only used in one specific problem (such as the names for the variables that appear), inventing your own notation is common practice. You need to write _something_, after all.

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to make use of subscripts $S_{li}$ and $S_{lina}$.